# Using a node package client-side with requireJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, requirejs

I need to parse some CSS files client-side in an app I'm building.  There is an excellent npm package that does just that:

https://github.com/NV/CSSOM

I'd like to take this package, smash it into a one file, and load it as a dependency in my requireJS implementation.  Essentially, I'd like to use it like this:

```
//A module in which I'll use CSSOM - I use CommonJS syntax almost exclusively
define( function(require) {
    var $ = require('jquery');
    var CSSOM = require('lib/CSSOM');
});
```

Full disclosure, I've never actually coded in node.js before (I'd just really like to use this module).  What can I do to make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Loading CSSOM as a non-AMD script

This will give you CSSOM in one file.

CSSOM has instructions to build it as a browser script, from its [github site](https://github.com/NV/CSSOM):

```
$ git clone https://github.com/NV/CSSOM.git
$ cd CSSOM
$ npm install -d
$ ./node_modules/.bin/jake
```

Based on what I see there, you'd then only need a `shim` configuration that states:

```
CSSOM: {
    exports: 'CSSOM'
}
```

#### Using `r.js`

This will give a bunch of modules making up CSSOM. If you'd want a final single file from this, you'd have to ask `r.js` to optimize the result of ding `r.js -convert`.

Use `r.js` to convert the code base of `CSSOM`:

```
$ r.js -convert in out
```

Where `in` is the source tree of `CSSOM` and `out` is where you want to result to be. Because CSSOM says it is pure JS this conversion will *probably* work without having to do anything else, because I'd expect `CSSOM` to not use Node-specific modules like `fs`. But there could be some other problems. If `CSSOM`, for instance, makes `require` calls that have a variable rather than a string literal as argument, the converter won't be able to convert it. At any rate, you should have a look at the [documentation](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js#convert-commonjs-modules) for details of what could go wrong.

Comment: Ok, that worked out great, but the library is still spread over a bunch of files.  I tried using the optimizer, but of course that requires a require config, etc.  Is there any way to compress all of these newly generated AMD modules into one file without turning this into a full blown require app, config and all?  Like can it maybe read the package.json and condense things into one file that way?

Comment: Sorry. I missed the "one file" requirement earlier. I've modified my answer to include another method to get what you want. You'd basically just using CSSOM's build facility to build it as a single script and then ask RequireJS to load it with a shim. This seems simpler to me than doing to `r.js` passes to get a final file.

Comment: Ha, I guess it's very convenient that CSSOM has a file for a build tool in it already.  From what I'm reading about jake, it seems like its one of many such build tools that "compile" node packages?  What if, in the future, I want to compile a package that doesn't have this "jakefile," or something similar for the build tool du jour.  Will I have to just use r.js convert, then write a build file, then use the r.js optimizer?

Comment: @AlexZ Yes, you'd have to use the `r.js` optimizer to build the module into a single file. And then there are those Node modules that cannot be converted because they depend on the Node.js runtime.